# Dependent CTEs in SQLAlchemy? (example inside)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Here is a very simple example in PostgreSQL:

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT 1 AS x
),   b AS ( 
    SELECT x AS y
    FROM a
)
SELECT y
FROM b;
```

How can I get SQLAlchemy to generate that (preferably using declarative)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works:

```
from sqlalchemy import literal

a = session.query(literal(1).label('x')).cte('a')
b = session.query(a.c.x.label('y')).cte('b')
res = session.query(b).all()

assert res[0].y == 1
```

Relevant documentation: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.CompoundSelect.cte